# How to move vbox virtual machine to different location along with snapshots

Tags: virtualbox

I have oracle virtualbox3.2 installed on ubuntu 9.10 desktop. It was working fine for a long time but suddenly today when I try to open virtualbox going to Applications>system tools> it's showing the below error message on a window:

```
Failed to create the VirtualBox COM object.
The application will now terminate.
Start tag expected, '<' not found.
Location: '/home/avyakta/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml', line 1 (0), column 1.
/home/vbox/vbox-3.2.6/src/VBox/Main/VirtualBoxImpl.cpp[535] (nsresult VirtualBox::init())
```

I also tried "sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup" but no use.

The 'Virtualbox.xml' file was empty, so I removed it and I re-registered vbox again. I had to add the VDIs again but it's not taking the snapshots having specified snapshot location. So I'm looking if there is any way I can make vdi's and its snapshots working.

EDIT 1:

Here is my xml file of vm named karmic:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.innotek.de/VirtualBox-settings" version="1.10-linux">
<Machine uuid="{1b896ca0-7168-400c-a5a2-f601df03b294}" name="Karmic"  OSType="Ubuntu" currentSnapshot="{dd4914df-07b2-43b3-988e-531a369bf6dd}" snapshotFolder="/part2/Karmic9.10/snpsht" lastStateChange="2010-11-30T09:05:57Z">
<ExtraData>
  <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastCloseAction" value="powerOff"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastGuestSizeHint" value="720,400"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastWindowPostion" value="290,248,720,450"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/MiniToolBarAlignment" value="bottom"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/SaveMountedAtRuntime" value="yes"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/ShowMiniToolBar" value="yes"/>
</ExtraData>
<Snapshot uuid="{dd4914df-07b2-43b3-988e-531a369bf6dd}" name="Snapshot 1" timeStamp="2010-11-25T08:45:09Z">
  <Hardware version="2">
    <CPU count="1" hotplug="false">
      <HardwareVirtEx enabled="true" exclusive="true"/>
      <HardwareVirtExNestedPaging enabled="true"/>
      <HardwareVirtExVPID enabled="true"/>
      <PAE enabled="true"/>
    </CPU>
<Memory RAMSize="512" PageFusion="false"/>
    <HID Pointing="USBTablet" Keyboard="PS2Keyboard"/>
    <HPET enabled="false"/>
    <Boot>
      <Order position="1" device="Floppy"/>
      <Order position="2" device="DVD"/>
      <Order position="3" device="HardDisk"/>
      <Order position="4" device="None"/>
    </Boot>
    <Display VRAMSize="12" monitorCount="1" accelerate3D="false" accelerate2DVideo="false"/>
    <RemoteDisplay enabled="false" port="3389" authType="Null" authTimeout="5000">
      <VideoChannel enabled="false" quality="75"/>
    </RemoteDisplay>
    <BIOS>
      <ACPI enabled="true"/>
      <IOAPIC enabled="false"/>
      <Logo fadeIn="true" fadeOut="true" displayTime="0"/>
      <BootMenu mode="MessageAndMenu"/>
      <TimeOffset value="0"/>
      <PXEDebug enabled="false"/>
</BIOS>
    <USBController enabled="true" enabledEhci="true"/>
    <Network>
      <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027F8AA0B" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
        <DisabledModes>
          <NAT>
            <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
            <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
          </NAT>
        </DisabledModes>
        <BridgedInterface name="eth0"/>
      </Adapter>
      <Adapter slot="1" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800271E816E" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
        <DisabledModes>
          <NAT>
            <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
<Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
          </NAT>
        </DisabledModes>
      </Adapter>
      <Adapter slot="2" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027897DD1" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
        <DisabledModes>
          <NAT>
            <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
            <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
          </NAT>
        </DisabledModes>
      </Adapter>
      <Adapter slot="3" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800272F8A63" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
        <DisabledModes>
          <NAT>
<DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
            <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
          </NAT>
        </DisabledModes>
      </Adapter>
      <Adapter slot="4" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800270F071A" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
        <DisabledModes>
          <NAT>
            <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
            <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
          </NAT>
        </DisabledModes>
      </Adapter>
      <Adapter slot="5" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027D69053" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
        <DisabledModes>
</Adapter>
      <Adapter slot="6" enabled="false" MACAddress="08002747E6BF" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
        <DisabledModes>
          <NAT>
            <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
            <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
          </NAT>
        </DisabledModes>
      </Adapter>
      <Adapter slot="7" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800275B2682" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
        <DisabledModes>
<NAT>
            <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
            <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
          </NAT>
        </DisabledModes>
      </Adapter>
    </Network>
    <UART>
      <Port slot="0" enabled="false" IOBase="0x3f8" IRQ="4" hostMode="Disconnected"/>
      <Port slot="1" enabled="false" IOBase="0x3f8" IRQ="4" hostMode="Disconnected"/>
    </UART>
    <LPT>
      <Port slot="0" enabled="false" IOBase="0x378" IRQ="4"/>
      <Port slot="1" enabled="false" IOBase="0x378" IRQ="4"/>
    </LPT>
    <AudioAdapter controller="AC97" driver="Pulse" enabled="true"/>
    <RTC localOrUTC="UTC"/>
    <SharedFolders/>
<Clipboard mode="Bidirectional"/>
    <IO>
      <IoCache enabled="true" size="5"/>
      <IoBandwidth max="0"/>
    </IO>
    <Guest memoryBalloonSize="0"/>
    <GuestProperties>
      <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/GUI/LanguageID" value="en_US" timestamp="1290674709753432000" flags=""/>
    </GuestProperties>
  </Hardware>
  <StorageControllers>
    <StorageController name="IDE Controller" type="PIIX4" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="true">
      <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" port="1" device="0"/>
    </StorageController>
    <StorageController name="SATA Controller" type="AHCI" PortCount="1" useHostIOCache="false" IDE0MasterEmulationPort="0" IDE0SlaveEmulationPort="1" IDE1MasterEmulationPort="2" IDE1SlaveEmulationPort="3">
      <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" port="0" device="0">
        <Image uuid="{f79e6efe-d019-4a2f-8d88-95f47cb07b01}"/>
</AttachedDevice>
    </StorageController>
  </StorageControllers>
</Snapshot>
<Hardware version="2">
  <CPU count="1" hotplug="false">
    <HardwareVirtEx enabled="true" exclusive="true"/>
    <HardwareVirtExNestedPaging enabled="true"/>
    <HardwareVirtExVPID enabled="true"/>
    <PAE enabled="true"/>
  </CPU>
  <Memory RAMSize="512" PageFusion="false"/>
  <HID Pointing="USBTablet" Keyboard="PS2Keyboard"/>
  <HPET enabled="false"/>
  <Boot>
    <Order position="1" device="Floppy"/>
    <Order position="2" device="DVD"/>
    <Order position="3" device="HardDisk"/>
    <Order position="4" device="None"/>
  </Boot>
  <Display VRAMSize="12" monitorCount="1" accelerate3D="false" accelerate2DVideo="false"/>
<RemoteDisplay enabled="false" port="3389" authType="Null" authTimeout="5000">
    <VideoChannel enabled="false" quality="75"/>
  </RemoteDisplay>
  <BIOS>
    <ACPI enabled="true"/>
    <IOAPIC enabled="false"/>
    <Logo fadeIn="true" fadeOut="true" displayTime="0"/>
    <BootMenu mode="MessageAndMenu"/>
    <TimeOffset value="0"/>
    <PXEDebug enabled="false"/>
  </BIOS>
  <USBController enabled="true" enabledEhci="true"/>
  <Network>
    <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027F8AA0B" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
      <DisabledModes>
        <NAT>
          <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
          <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
</NAT>
      </DisabledModes>
      <BridgedInterface name="eth0"/>
    </Adapter>
    <Adapter slot="1" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800271E816E" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
      <DisabledModes>
        <NAT>
          <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
          <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
        </NAT>
      </DisabledModes>
    </Adapter>
    <Adapter slot="2" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027897DD1" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
      <DisabledModes>
        <NAT>
          <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
          <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
        </NAT>
</DisabledModes>
    </Adapter>
    <Adapter slot="3" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800272F8A63" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
      <DisabledModes>
        <NAT>
          <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
          <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
        </NAT>
      </DisabledModes>
    </Adapter>
    <Adapter slot="4" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800270F071A" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
      <DisabledModes>
        <NAT>
          <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
          <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
        </NAT>
      </DisabledModes>
    </Adapter>
<Adapter slot="5" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027D69053" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
      <DisabledModes>
        <NAT>
          <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
          <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
        </NAT>
      </DisabledModes>
    </Adapter>
    <Adapter slot="6" enabled="false" MACAddress="08002747E6BF" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
      <DisabledModes>
        <NAT>
          <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
          <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
        </NAT>
      </DisabledModes>
    </Adapter>
    <Adapter slot="7" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800275B2682" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
      <DisabledModes>
<NAT>
          <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
          <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
        </NAT>
      </DisabledModes>
    </Adapter>
  </Network>
  <UART>
    <Port slot="0" enabled="false" IOBase="0x3f8" IRQ="4" hostMode="Disconnected"/>
    <Port slot="1" enabled="false" IOBase="0x3f8" IRQ="4" hostMode="Disconnected"/>
  </UART>
  <LPT>
    <Port slot="0" enabled="false" IOBase="0x378" IRQ="4"/>
    <Port slot="1" enabled="false" IOBase="0x378" IRQ="4"/>
  </LPT>
 <AudioAdapter controller="AC97" driver="Pulse" enabled="true"/>
  <RTC localOrUTC="UTC"/>
  <SharedFolders/>
  <Clipboard mode="Bidirectional"/>
  <IO>
    <IoCache enabled="true" size="5"/>
    <IoBandwidth max="0"/>
  </IO>
  <Guest memoryBalloonSize="0"/>
  <GuestProperties>
    <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/GUI/LanguageID" value="en_US" timestamp="1290674709753432000" flags=""/>
  </GuestProperties>
</Hardware>
<StorageControllers>
  <StorageController name="IDE Controller" type="PIIX4" PortCount="2"  useHostIOCache="true">
    <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" port="1" device="0"/>
  </StorageController>
  <StorageController name="SATA Controller" type="AHCI" PortCount="1"     useHostIOCache="false" IDE0MasterEmulationPort="0" IDE0SlaveEmulationPort="1"     IDE1MasterEmulationPort="2" IDE1SlaveEmulationPort="3">
 <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" port="0" device="0">
      <Image uuid="{65de14de-f434-469b-a494-528e74e64938}"/>
    </AttachedDevice>
    </StorageController>
   </StorageControllers>
  </Machine>
</VirtualBox>
```

Any help..?

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that the title fits to the text? "Suddenly" does not seem to involve moving VBox to a different location, does it ;)?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Snapshot information in VirtualBox is stored in various places:

- Inside the ~/.Virtualbox/Machines/MachineName/Snapshots, there should be a VDI file per snapshot and some .sav files (one for each snapshot and one for the current state if it was saved). I'm not sure, but I bet that .vdi store the hard disk state and the .sav memory and other states.
- The file ~/.Virtualbox/Machines/ManchineName.xml, stores all the virtual machine setting, including snapshots.

If you recreated the VM chances are that you MachineName.xml file has been overwrited. You will have to recreate it (likely by hand).

This are the relevant lines in the .xml file of a test VM that I use.

```
<Machine uuid="{b174a63e-19ce-4291-9b07-083916f3d316}" name="Probas" OSType="Ubuntu" stateFile="Snapshots/{b174a63e-19ce-4291-9b07-083916f3d316}.sav" currentSnapshot="{3ecc12c8-c27e-4574-9e79-59503777173f}" lastStateChange="2010-11-16T16:52:34Z">
<Snapshot uuid="{3ecc12c8-c27e-4574-9e79-59503777173f}" name="Ubuntu reciente" timeStamp="2010-08-12T20:38:36Z" stateFile="Snapshots/{3ecc12c8-c27e-4574-9e79-59503777173f}.sav">
```

You will likely need to add a Snapshot... line for each snapshot in your dir.

Not really tested, hope that it works.

Comment: Oh, very strange situation. I'll try this.

Comment: It's entirely different in my xml file. There is no such word like 'Machine' and 'Snapshot'. After adding the vdis newly again, I created a snapshot for a vdi and checked in the xml file that how its adding. In the similar fashion I added my old snapshot and checked, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you checking each machine xml not VirtualBox.xml?.

Comment: Can you post the xml somewhere?. I'd try to read it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't check each machines xml. I've posted my xml file of vm.

Comment: There is a <Machine uuid...> tag on line 3 and a <Snapshot...> tag on line 12.